# Duplicate tf messages with robot_state_publisher and coded tfs

Tags: ros2, transform, tf2, tf2-ros

From what I understand, `robot_state_publisher` reads the `urdf` and publishes the default frames to the `/tf_static` and the `/tf` topic. How do you publish a message to the tf topic? When I do, there's now 2 messages for the parent_frame/child_frame pair and it rubber-bands/gitters between the 2 positions because it's trying to be at both position at once, which is impossible. Any ideas and resources to point me to?

Working code the publishes a message to the `/tf` topic.

```
        geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped t;
        std::string parent_frame = "pxxls_1/pan_link";
        std::string child_frame = "pxxls_1/tilt_link";
        try {
            t = tf_buffer_->lookupTransform(
                parent_frame,
                child_frame,
                tf2::TimePointZero
            );
        }
        catch (const tf2::TransformException& ex) {
            RCLCPP_INFO(
                get_logger(), "Could not transform %s to %s: %s",
                parent_frame.c_str(), child_frame.c_str(), ex.what());
            return;
        }

        double angle_in_radians = M_PI / 4.0; // 45 degrees in radians
        tf2::Quaternion quaternion;
        quaternion.setRPY(0.0, 0.0, angle_in_radians);  // Roll, pitch, and yaw angles
        t.transform.rotation.x = quaternion.x();
        t.transform.rotation.y = quaternion.y();
        t.transform.rotation.z = quaternion.z();
        t.transform.rotation.w = quaternion.w();

        tf_broadcaster_->sendTransform(t);
```

#### Reference

- https://wiki.ros.org/tf/Theory
- https://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher/Tutorials/Using%20the%20robot%20state%20publisher%20on%20your%20own%20robot
- https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Intermediate/URDF/Using-URDF-with-Robot-State-Publisher.html

Answer (score 0):

Publish joint movements to the `/joint_states` topic. The `robot_state_publisher` will read `/joint_states` and correctly publish to the `/tf` topic.